# SQL plugin tools to monitor data inserted realtime

Tags: sql

is there any plugin/tools for SQL DB monitoring
i would like to know what has been inserted into which table/column when the 3rd party app writes the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Profiler which comes with most editions of SQL Server can be configured to monitor transactions against specific databases and/or logins.

Answer (score 0):

[newrelic](https://newrelic.com/) is pretty useful for such requirements

Comment: cannot find download link. i need standalone app...this seems must online and login?

Comment: good point, Joe. But i cannot really offer any more details, because the question does not specify which type of SQL should be monitored. newrelic is a tool that needs to be installed on your server... it has a plugin for i.e mysql (https://newrelic.com/plugins/new-relic-inc/52). you can see all your stats of all your servers in your newrelic account on their website